# How do I print out one row from a 2D array given a parameter?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm given a parameter in which the user chooses which row he wants me to print out, how do I print out the row that the user wants?

This is my 2D array:  Jewel[][] myGrid;

```
 public Jewel[] getRow(int row) { 
     return null; 
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the code where your 2-d array is shown?

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that Aomine?

Comment: @Issa You need to add an `@` symbol in front of his name, else he will not be notified and probably not read your comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a detailed description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) *does not work*, *please help me* are not acceptable.

Comment: this brings help vampirism to a new low

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the first dimension of your `Jewel[][] myGrid` is the row index:

```
public Jewel[] getRow(int row) { 
    return myGrid[row]; 
}
```

If the second dimension in the row index:

```
public Jewel[] getRow(int row) { 
    Jewel[] result = new Jewel[myGrid.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.length; i++) {
        result[i] = myGrid[i][row];
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Then you simply call

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRow(0)));
```

Answer (score -1):

run a for loop to cycle through that row by getting the amount of columns in that row. In each loop, get that number from the 2d array and add it to a list. Return that list. I can write the code for you if you need.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myGrid[row].length; i++){
    System.out.println(myGrid[row][i]);
}
```

Comment: could you please write the code, it would make it easier for me to understand

Comment: @Issa  sure. Ill edit it in a minute.

Comment: @Issa let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: I hope someone gets to take your code and get credit for it and paid for in the very near future.

Comment: @gkgkgkgk Why did you make an ArrayList and add that onto myGrid?

Comment: @Issa I just organized it into a list so that the method will return the Jewel[] with its contents. The important part is the for loop that cycles through the row in the 2d array. technically you can remove the entire use of the ArrayList and return null, but then you should just make it a regular function without a return type.